# Use variable from one page in another - Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I have the following structure:

[Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0Xbn.png)

In the app.component.ts I have a variable "valor", I want to use that variable in app-routing.module.ts

[app.component.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaphD.png)

[app-routing.module.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Qwpt.png)

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

As *Sid T* pointed it, you could use Nav Parameters. For instance, you would navigate like this:

**app.component.ts**

```
goToThisPage(variable) {
    this.navCtrl.push(TargetPage, {
      param: variable
    });
}
```

and would retrieve the variable like this:

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
this.xyz = this.navParams.get('param');
```

Comment: this question relates to Ionic 4 and I guess it's better to leverage something else than NavController that only supports non-lazy components nowadays. Also Unclear how your answer can help in this specific use case as there are no "pages" really.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to use a common variable in any of page is to use provider.
First generate provider in your project using following command :

> ionic generate provider provider_name

and declare that common variable as a public in this provider like :

```
public test:string = "";
```

Now, import and inject this provider in any of page that you want to use that common variable as below :

```
import {provider_name} from '../..';
constructor(private testPvdr:TestProvider) {}
```

Now, you can use that common variable by just provider :

```
alert(this.testPvdr.test);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Nav Params](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/navigation/NavParams/) to transfer data from one page to another.